# Is it possible to have yui editor change paragraph style without selecting text?

Tags: yui, yui-editor

Is it possible to change the behavior of the yui text editor so that when you make markup changes (via the toolbar bar buttons), for example changing from a paragraph to say a heading or to a list, and you dont have any text selected it assumes you mean the current block that the cursor is in

So to change a paragraph to a heading rather than selecting the whole line you just place the cursor somewhere in the paragraph and select heading from the styles drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dav Glass on yahoo groups answered this for me with:

Try setting the insert config option: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.SimpleEditor.html#config_insert Dav ... -- Dav Glass davglass@... ...